# How to fix time to 00:01:00 in current-dateTime function output in XSLT?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am using select="fn:current-dateTime()+ xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') to get current date + 1 day as final output. But I want to fix the time to 00:01 in output. How can I do this?

I am new to XSLT.I have tried replace function but not working.

Comment: In what timezone should the resulting dateTime be?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dateTime(current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'), xs:time('00:01:00'))
```

Note that this will preserve the local timezone returned by the `current-date()` function; for example, if your timezone is 5.5 hours ahead of GMT, you will get a result of `2022-11-03T00:01:00+05:30` if you run the evaluation today (2022-11-02).